# Web Hosting with FrontPage Extension

Tags: web-hosting, frontpage

Anyone knows a good web hosting provider that has frontpage extension?

I was using godaddy before. now they are not supporting frontpage anymore. :(

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but:

I think the reason is: Frontpage extensions were always buggy and caused security breaches on servers. And the fact that Microsoft doesn't sell Frontpage anymore, but has replaced it with other tools about 4 years ago.

I'd strongly suggest moving to other tools. Something that would be supported going forward. If i were in your shoes, I'd look for tools and a hosting provider that supported WebDav.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [BlueHost](http://www.bluehost.com/cgi/info/hosting_features). Been with them for 2+ years. Pretty happy with everything. A screenshot from my BlueHost Control Panel:

[image]